# Using \polyremainder in polynom package

Tags: polynom

The [documentation of the `polynom` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polynom.pdf) refers in chapter "4.6 Low-level commands" (p. 6) to a command called `\polyremainder`, which should display only the remainder of a polynomial division. I'm not quite sure how to use it, but even calling the command yields the following error: `Undefined control sequence. \polyremainder`

I've already tried the following:

```
\polyadd\polya{x^4}{0}
\polyadd\polyb{x^4+2x^3+2x+1}{0}
\polyremainder
```

and

```
\polyadd\polya{x^4}{0}
\polyadd\polyb{x^4+2x^3+2x+1}{0}
\polyremainder\polya\polyb
```

The local copy of `polynom` is the most recent version on CTAN (2006/04/20 0.17 (CH,HA)).

Using TeX Live 2015 on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit

Comment: don't you need to divide, instead of adding to get a remainder? According to the definition of the package, `\polyremainder` is only set if `\polydiv` is given first.

Comment: @RunarTrollet Thanks, calling `\polydiv` first solves the issue. Actually, I've missed that the `\polyremainder` line in the documentation isn't meant to be on its own. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the remainder you need to do a division first, and in `polynom` you need to do `\polydiv` before `\polyremainder`.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
 \polyadd\polya { (X^2+X+1)(X-2) }{0}
    \polyadd\polyb { X-1 }{0}


Dividing \polyprint\polya{} by \polyprint\polyb.
\[\polylongdiv\polya\polyb\]

\polydiv\polyc{ (X^2+X+1)(X-2) }{ X-1 }
Remainder is: \polyprint{\polyremainder}
\end{document}
```